# Github code review shows blank lines after, how to remove them?

Tags: git, github, whitespace, blank-line, github-codereviews

Here is my work flow:

```
git pull origin master
git checkout -b test
```

Make some changes

```
git add .
git commit -m"Add changes"
git push origin test
```

Then in code review, I saw some empty lines, so instead of change formatting line by line, I reset that file to be like origin/master

```
git checkout origin/master fileA
```

Then this time, I only add the part that needs to change and didn't touch any other part.

```
git add fileA
git commit -m"Remove empty lines"
git push origin test
```

But in github, I still see some unwanted lines. 
How can I remove them?

For example, those lines are exactly the same, they should not be highlighted:
[image]

Note:

- I can't show other code (because it's work repo) that is similar or
  have empty lines like this.
- There's no githook to run the format.
- It's a Jenkinsfile

Comment: Can you please specify what is the `fileA` extension? Do you have some sort of the git hook defined?

Comment: what is your lineending (cr or crlf)? please provide a screenshot of the problem